# Add Aspectj Runtime Library to project via .classpath file

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

I have a python script that downloads the latest svn build, then converts the project to an aspectj project and adds the necessary libraries , except for the Aspectj Runtime Library. I have my script trying to add the library in to the `.classpath` file like so: `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="/Users/rovimacmini/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.0/aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar"/>` but I get an error that the `aspectjrt.jar isn't in the classpath`. Does anyone know how I can add it via the `.classpath` file so that my java build path has the AspectJ Runtime Library in it like so:

[image: Picture of goal.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you manually create an AspectJ project in Eclipse and just look at how Eclipse does it.

**.project** needs an 'ajbuilder' and an 'ajnature':

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>AspectJ_Project</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects></projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
            <arguments></arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

**.classpath** needs a container ("con") classpath entry for the AspectJ runtime:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ASPECTJRT_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**Update:** I also tried replacing the container entry provided by AJDT by a direct reference to a manually installed library in my local file system like this:

```xml
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Java/AspectJ/lib/aspectjrt.jar"/>
```

It works nicely. So in this case it is not `con`, but `lib` type. In my experience it also is not necessary to set the `exported` property, you can just skip that one.